# PHP CURL in iframe change base url?

Tags: php, iframe, curl

I'm using a CURL call to an API. The call gives back a HTML DOM tree that i echo inside an iframe. The problem is that the base url refers to my own site instead of the API's site. For example: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/swf/swfobject.js"></script>` will refer to my website instead of the API's. I have looked at the CURL set options but i couldn't find what i'm looking for, could someone please help me? I tried using preg_replace which worked but i have a lot of diffrent inpredictable links. (and its way to dirty!)

Code of CURL call:

```
function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    // Optional Authentication:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    return curl_exec($curl);
}


$output = CallAPI($method, $url, $data);

echo $output;
```

HTML:

```
<iframe src="videorecorder.php" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Please help me!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[CURLOPT_REFERER](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
```

Comment: Thanks but it isn't working for me. Maybe i'm doing something wrong. I put this line after the switch statement: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.google.com");` I still get this error `GET http://www.mywebsite.com/swf/history/history.js 404 (Not Found) ` instead of google.com .

Comment: I'm making a call to an API which returns a HTML page that i put in an iframe on my page. Links to certain CSS/JS files on their server are referenced to like this: `src="/swf/swfobject.js`. The base href that gets used in my iframe is the base href of my website, but the files arn't on my website, they are on theirs! So the base href should be the same as the one of the API. So how do i use or change it to the right base href?

Comment: It is not cURL related question. Check your $url variable.